# How to configure Angular 6 URL rewrite in dotnet core using IIS appsettings.json

Tags: angular, .net-core

I'm deploying an Angular SPA to my .NET Core app using IIS.

I do a production Angular build (ng build --base-href /ng --deploy-url /ng) and deploy it to wwwroot in the ng directory.

I currently have it working when you manually go to the Angular url for index.html:

```
https://localhost:44316/ng/index.html
```

However, if you refresh or manually navigate to a url, you get a 404.

```
https://localhost:44316/ng/dash
```

Not surprising, given that Angular says this will happen without a URL redirect. In the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml), it says to insert a rewrite rule into web.config.

However, I'm using .NET Core, and one of my team members has informed me that modifying the web.config XML is the old way of doing things. It looks like I need to modify appsettings.json to make this rewrite rule happen.

Soo....Anyone done this before? If I don't modify web.config to set up my forward, how do I set it up?

Comment: The web.config can still be used for some configuration settings, especially when hosting in IIS. You colleague was correct in that web.config is no longer used for application settings but you will still need it for IIS configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I forget where I found this little code snippet, but it did the trick. I used the following in Configure() in Startup.cs:

```
        app.Run(async (context) =>
       {
           context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
           await context.Response.SendFileAsync(Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, "ng/index.html"));
       });
```

Basically, on all the pages in my ng directory, it will load up index.html (without changing the url).

Comment: I was facing same issue with .NET 6 WebAPI + Angular 13 SPA deployed on Azure App Service.  Worked perfectly after applying your solution.  In my case, the content was in `wwwroot` folder itself.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using hash strategy to confirm that this may be a server misconfiguration?
Usually 404 happens when the server is not pointing to the "main angular's page", which is the index.html you mentioned.

To use hash strategy you just need to add this parameter to your RouterModule import:

> RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})

Comment: Not sure if that would have worked or not, but found a solution of my own (which I posted here).